# Javascript When and Done Function use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call two different functions in third function but one after the other.One function has ajax call, whose values are used in other function. it is step by step process. I don't want to use one into the other.

```
function f1()
{
    // ajax call 
    return r1
}

function f2(r2)
{
    // do some of the work based on r2
}

function f3()
{
    $.when(f1()).done(function(data){
            f2(data)

    });
}
```

I also tried with $.when().then(); but still of no use.

Thanks, in advance.

UPDATE :- Below is the answer for my Question based on solution provide by @dreamweiver.

```
var json_data = '';
function f1()
{

    $.ajax({
         url: "test.php",
         method: "POST",
         async : false,
         data: { },
         success:function(data){
            json_data = eval(data);
         }

       });  


}

function f2(t)
{

    console.log("values is "+t);
}

function f3()
{
    $.when(f1()).done(function(){
        f2(json_data);
   });
}
```

Thanks everyone for your feedbacks.

Comment: Did you try `$.when(f1).done(function(data){
            f2(data)

    });`

Comment: If you're using jQuery's `ajax()` then you should just be able to do: `f1().then(f2)`.

Comment: why do you need the f3 function? presumably you want to set the promise then call f1?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `()` after your `f1` call? ie. `$.when(f1).done(...` - if you call it with `()` then the function will execute instantly. What you probably should be doing is passing it as a variable for jQuery to execute later

Comment: @James, i tried ur method but it shows "f1  is undefined" error

Comment: i treid removing parenthesis, but it does nothing. not event it shows error. I checked in console.

Comment: It should do nothing, after declaration you should call `f1()`.

Comment: But there is some functionality added in f2 which is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, I have tested locally and it works perfectly

```
function deferredCalls () {
   var jsonData = '';
   var f1 = function ()
   {
       // ajax call 
       $.ajax({
         url: "test.html",
         method: "POST",
         data: { id : menuId }
       }).done(function(data) {
          jsonData = data; //set the data
       });
   }

   var f2 = function (data)
   {
     // do some of the work based on data
     if(!!data){
       //process the data
     }
   }
   $.when(f1).done(function(){
        f2(jsonData);
   });
 }
```

`f1` function is called first which would in turn make a ajax request and return data on success, which is set to a function scope variable `jsonData`. Once this process is completed, f2 would be called which will start using `jsonData`, which is nothing but the data received from `f1` function call.

Comment: With this, i wont be able to call f1 & f2 in some other functions.

Comment: well thats not a  issue, move those functions into global scope  & leave rest as it is.

Comment: Did you try moving complete definition of `f1=func....` ,`f2=func.....` & `jsonData` into global scope from `deferredCalls()`?

Comment: The `$.when` doesn't get a hold of the promise created by `$.ajax`. What the code is doing in general is: `$.when` calls `f1`, `f1` returns undefined, `$.when` passes that as the parameter to the anonymous callback to `.done`, this calls `f2` with `jsonData` that hasn't been initialized (the only exception being that the ajax call synchronously triggers the `.done` within f1). So this doesn't do anything useful at all

Comment: @vanhelgen, correctly said. Its doing the same thing sometimes and other times it show as "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

This should be working:

```
function f1() {
    // Or some other Ajax request that returns a promise
    return $.getJSON('path/to/your/service');
}

function f2(r2) {
    // ...
}

f1().done(f2);
```